# JsonConvert SerializeObject not correctly serializing String Array

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-serialization

I'm posting some JSON to a REST server using the following RestConnector:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static T httpPost(String myURL, Dictionary<string, string> data) {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myURL);
    Console.WriteLine("Sending Request to: " + myURL);

    request.Method = "POST";

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);


    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("JSON: "+ json);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(json);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

    Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
    newStream.Close();
    //...
}
```

**I'm getting the following error back from the server*:**

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING

Upon further investigation, this is the raw JSON that's being posted:

```
{
    "tag1":"val1",
    "tag2":"System.String[]", 
    ...
}
```

How can I serialize this object so that the array is sent properly?

*Example:*

```
{
    "tag1":"val1",
    "tag2":[],
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

**This is where I create the object that I'm serializing:**

```
    MyObject mo =new MyObject();
    mo.tag1= "val1";
    mo.tag2= new String[]{};

    Dictionary<string, string> input = objectToDictionary(mo);

    mo = RestConnector<MyObject>.httpPost("http://example.com", input);
```

***objectToDictionary***

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> objectToDictionary(object obj) {
     return obj.GetType().GetProperties()
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(obj)?.ToString() ?? "");
 }
```

Comment: Surely the problem here is in your dictionary? Before you even get into this method you've already got a dictionary of strings, where the value of tag2 is "System.String[]"

Comment: Editing to add how the how the data is added to the dictionary

Comment: yep so your problem here is that ToString on a String[] just returns the name of the type. Is there a reason you can't just pass MyObject into your httpPost method and serialize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your `objectToDictionary` method, the `ToString` implementation for an array of string simply returns `"System.String[]"`.

You have to change your implementation so that Json.Net receives the string array directly, he'll figure out how to serialize it.